# List all namespaces in Firefox with XSLT

Tags: firefox, xslt

In XSLT, I try to list all namespaces in the document. Here is the code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>:
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If I run it in Chrome or Safari, it works well. But Firefox shows no results: "namespace::" is empty.

Does anybody know if there is an alternative selector for all namespaces in a document?

Comment: Mozilla's XPath implementation, I think, neglected the namespace axis so there is no easy way out. There is Saxon JS 2 however, an XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1 implementation in Javascript, that can be used and might have better cross-browser compatibility than the different XSLT/XPath 1 engines of the different browsers. If you want to do it pure XSLT/XPath 1, I think a tool named XPath visualizer by Dimitre Novatchev exists or existed in a Mozilla version and probably solved that problem of the missing namespace axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been an open bug for 18 years:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94270

You can find all the namespaces that are actually used using `namespace-uri()` on every element and attribute, but I don't think there's any other way of finding namespaces that aren't used.

Of course (I declare a personal interest here) you could switch horses and use Saxon-JS.